# Update Specific data to record using mysql query

Tags: mysql

Actually am newbie to MySQL, I want to `UPDATE` a particular record in my table by using `UPDATE QUERY` that table contains multiple entry what I need is selecting the last inserted record and incrementing that record by 2 in a monthly basis by Googling I got some idea for selecting

My Selecting query:

```
SELECT `accumulatedleave`,`leaveincredit`
FROM info 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(`sl_no`) as `sl_no` FROM info GROUP BY `fullname`) last_updates 
ON last_updates.`sl_no` = info.`sl_no`;
```

Here `sl_no` is my primary key with `AUTO_INCREMENT` and `fullname` is my username, one more field is there that capture timestamp.

Regards,
sufiyan

Comment: Please clarify which fields from which table you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which value and table you want to update but you might be able to do something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1field = (SELECT MAX(table2.table2field) FROM table2 WHERE table1.table1field = table2.table2field)
```

Hope it helps :)